# Function inside Flatlist RenderItem is not fully working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Problem is I cannot see {item.key} inside my function. When I type {item.key} itself inside flatlist render it is working. But inside function only {item.value} is showing. Can anyone explain to me why this happening ?

**Sample Data**

```
const orderResultJson = [
  {
    key: 'Скачайте приложение по ссылке',
    value: 'https://google.com'
  },
  {
    key: 'Логин',
    value: '879854'
  },
  {
    key: 'Пароль',
    value: '849846'
  },
];
```

**My Function**

```
function DetailsSection(item){
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>{item.value}</Text>
      <Text>{item.key}+test</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

**Render**

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={orderResultJson}
          renderItem={({item}) => <DetailsSection {...item} />} 
          keyExtractor={item => item.key} 
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem here is, when you are deconstructing `item` as individual props, the prop `key` will be considered as in built react prop `key` instead of considering it as an external prop.

So instead of deconstructing, pass `item` as is and access it from your function as it is.

My Function

```
function DetailsSection({ item }){
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>{item.value}</Text>
      <Text>{item.key}+test</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Render

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={orderResultJson}
        renderItem={({item}) => <DetailsSection item={item} />} 
        keyExtractor={item => item.key} 
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank bro, understood better now

Answer (score 2):

```
function DetailsSection(props){
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>{props.item.key} + test</Text>
      <Text>{props.item.value}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Or

pass like this

```
<DetailsSection item={item} />
```

and access like this

```
function DetailsSection({ item }){
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>{item.value}</Text>
      <Text>{item.key}+test</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

because you are passing extracted value so directly you can access

Comment: Check it out https://snack.expo.io/@jasurkurbanov/updated2 
still not working